# can't read array fields in php(woocommerce)

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

i'm using woocommerce api in my php codes

but i have a problem in my code

how can i access to my array content

i want to echo each fields

```
$cats = $client->products->get_categories();

$arrlength = count($cats);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

echo $userid,$cats[$x]['name']) ;

}
```

result of my array is :

```
  Array
(
    [product_categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 23
                    [name] => Business
                    [slug] => business
                    [parent] => 21
                    [description] => 
                    [display] => default
                    [image] => 
                    [count] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 24
                    [name] => Business
                    [slug] => business-woman
                    [parent] => 22
                    [description] => 
                    [display] => default
                    [image] => 
                    [count] => 7
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [name] => Casual
                    [slug] => casual
                    [parent] => 22
                    [description] => 
                    [display] => default
                    [image] => 
                    [count] => 7
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 26
                    [name] => Casual
                    [slug] => casual-men
                    [parent] => 21
                    [description] => 
                    [display] => default
                    [image] => 
                    [count] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [name] => Featured
                    [slug] => featured
                    [parent] => 0
                    [description] => FEATURED PRODUCT
                    [display] => default
                    [image] => 
                    [count] => 10
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21
                    [name] => Men
                    [slug] => men
                    [parent] => 0
                    [description] => 
                    [display] => default
                    [image] => 
                    [count] => 5
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22
                    [name] => Women
                    [slug] => women
                    [parent] => 0
                    [description] => 
                    [display] => default
                    [image] => 
                    [count] => 12
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$categories = $client->products->get_categories();
foreach($categories['product_categories'] as $categorie) {
   foreach($categorie as $key => $value) {
       echo $key . ' is ' . $value . '<br>'; 
   }
   echo '<hr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($cats as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value["id"];
    echo $value["name"];
    echo $value["slug"];
    echo $value["parent"];
    echo $value["description"];
    echo $value["display"];
    echo $value["image"];
    echo $value["count"];
}
```

Comment: thank you for fast replay

but i got this errors

Undefined index: name 
Undefined index: slug 
Undefined index: parent 
Undefined index: description 
Undefined index: display 
Undefined index: image 
Undefined index: count